# vuejs router children show

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

the router works very well under normal conditions, but I keep repeating and
"/news"
"/news/:id"
"/news/:id/edit"
I wanted to define children in order not to write, but I noticed something like this. I need to define  in children "news.vue" and it opens in it. what i want.
How can I make it possible to close the news and open the link I clicked instead?

MainApp.vue

```
<template>
    <div>
        <app-header></app-header>
        <app-menu></app-menu>
        <transition name="fade" mode="out-in">
            <router-view></router-view>
        </transition>
        <app-footer></app-footer>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from "./shared/Header";
import Menu from "./shared/Menu";
import Footer from "./shared/Footer";

export default {
    components: {
        appHeader: Header,
        appMenu: Menu,
        appFooter: Footer,
    }
}
</script>
<style>
.fade-enter {
    opacity: 0;
}

.fade-enter-active {
    transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
}

.fade-leave {
}

.fade-leave-active {
    transition: opacity .2s ease-out;
    opacity: 0;
}
</style>
```

router.js

```
import News from "./components/News";
import Newsitem from "./components/Newsitem";
Vue.use(VueRouter);
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/news',
        name: 'news',
        component: News,
        children: [
            {
                path: ':id',
                name: 'newsitem',
                component: Newsitem,
            }
        ]
    },
];
export const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: "history",
    routes
})
```

Answer (score 0):

When you do not open children in parent component, then just do not use children:

```
const routes = [
    {
        path: '/news',
        name: 'news',
        component: News        
    },
    {
        path: '/news/:id',
        name: 'newsitem',
        component: Newsitem        
    },
];
```